# Equation numbering latex problem

Tags: math-mode, equations

I don't know where the error in my equation or numbering code is, but everything is red. I tried fixing it, but as I am a newby with latex I didnt find a solution.

Can someone help me with that?

I want to number those equations:
For the first one, I can see the equation number, but for the others it doesn't work..

```
\vspace{22pt}
\begin{centering}
\begin{equation}

    \begin{align}

        $\begin{array}{rrrr}
        m\textsubscript{11} & m\textsubscript{12} & m\textsubscript{13} & m\textsubscript{14} \\

        m\textsubscript{21} & m\textsubscript{22} & m\textsubscript{23} & m\textsubscript{24} \\

        m\textsubscript{31} & m\textsubscript{32} & m\textsubscript{33} & m\textsubscript{34} \\

        m\textsubscript{41} & m\textsubscript{42} & m\textsubscript{43} & m\textsubscript{44} \\
        \end {array}$
    \end{align}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \[ \left( \begin{array}{rrrr}
            0 & 0 & 1 & t\textsubscript{x} \\                                               
            -1 & 0 & 0 & t\textsubscript{y} \\                                               
            0 & -1 & 0 & t\textsubscript{z} \\   
            0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
    \end{array} \right)
    %
    \left( \begin{array}{rrrr}
                x \\
                y \\
                z \\
                1 \\
    \end{array} \right) 
    \]
\end{equation}
\end{centering}

\vspace{22pt}


\subsubsection{Translation matrix}
\par

TEXT

\begin{equation}

    \begin{align}

        \[ \left( \begin{array}{rrrr}
        0 & 0 & 1 & 5.39 \\                                               
        -1 & 0 & 0 & 6.26\\                                               
        0 & -1 & 0 & 4.275 \\   
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
        \end{array} \right)
        %
        \left( \begin{array}{rrrr}
                x \\
                y \\
                z \\
                1 \\
        \end{array} \right)
        \]
    \end{alignn}
\end{equation}
\vspace{22pt}
```

It looks like that:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: you can not have blank lines in equation, but also you should not have `align` inside equation, and do not surround it with `\begin{centering}`  so just have `\begin{equation}` You do not want `align` here

Comment: (1) no blank lines in math mode, (2) `align` inside `equation` does not make sense, (3) references to equation numbers are made using `\label` and `\ref` none of which are in this example

Comment: for the later ones remove `\[`  do not ignore errors, if you get a tex error ask about the error message, not about the generated pdf (which is not intended to be usable after an error)

Comment: I tried to change my code with your suggestions, but I still can't see the numbers.. and still a lot of red lines..

Comment: Also remove the dollars around your first array. You are already in math mode here.

Comment: oh perfect thank you. So the first one isn't red anymore and I can see the equation number... the matrix vector multiplication is still a catostrophy :(

Comment: O the \[ where also not necessary because I am already in the math mode? second one also fixed !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With use of the `mathtools` and `siunitx` package and considering comments to your question, one of among possible solutions is:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
        m^{11} & m^{12} & m^{13} & m^{14} \\
        m^{21} & m^{22} & m^{23} & m^{24} \\
        m^{31} & m^{32} & m^{33} & m^{34} \\
        m^{41} & m^{42} & m^{43} & m^{44} \\
\end{pmatrix}
    \end{equation}

    \begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    0 &  0 & 1 & t\textsubscript{x} \\
   -1 &  0 & 0 & t\textsubscript{y} \\
    0 & -1 & 0 & t\textsubscript{z} \\
    0 &  0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix*}\begin{pmatrix}
                x \\
                y \\
                z \\
                1 \\
            \end{pmatrix}
    \end{equation}

\subsubsection{Translation matrix}
TEXT

\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{rrrS[table-format=1.3]}
    0 &  0 & 1 & 5.39 \\
   -1 &  0 & 0 & 6.26\\
    0 & -1 & 0 & 4.275 \\
    0 &  0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)\begin{pmatrix}
                x \\
                y \\
                z \\
                1 \\
            \end{pmatrix}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]